Extract `mediaLink` of each uploaded file to firebase storage on multiple upload using NodeJS server
I'm trying to extract the mediaLink and name properties from each uploaded file to firebase storage, however, what happen is that the files are uploaded successfully but the response is an empty object. What I want is to respond with a collection of objects containing each file properties.
// upload multiple files
router.post('/bucket/uploadfiles/many', upload.any(), async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const files = req.files;

// check if files is empty
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.send('No file sent.');
    }

// collecting promises returned by upload() method
    const uploadedPromises = files.map((file) => {
      return bucket.upload(file.path, { public: true }).then((data) => {

// extracting desired properties from metadata
        const uploadedFile = data[0];
        return {
          name: uploadedFile.metadata.name,
          downloadUrl: uploadedFile.metadata.mediaLink,
        };
      });
    });


    const uploadedFiles = await Promise.all(uploadedPromises);

    console.log(uploadedFiles); // I get the objects as expected

    res.send(uploadedFiles); // this is sent before the promise is resolved thus an empty object
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
});

Could someone please help me to understand what I'm missing here.
